# Inherit Spring configuration from another WAR

Tags: java, spring-mvc

We have a SpringMVC project called "Framework" in Eclipse and a "New project" that must inherit from the "Framework" configuration.

Both Spring projects are not using .xml configuration files.

The "Framework" contains all business classes, datasource configuration and ContextListener default behavior that we don't want to rewrite each time we start a new project.

The "Framework" is loaded as a Maven overlay in the second project.

As you can see below, it is a very basic sample SpringMVC configuration.

**Framework**

```
-- main
    -- java
        -- config
            - AppConfig.class (implements WebMvcConfigurer)
            - AppInit.class (implements WebApplicationInitializer)
```

**AppConfig.class**

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="main.java")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ControllerLoggingInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*");
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/images");
    }
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages","classpath:/framework/messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(838860800);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

**AppInit.class**

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Autowired
    MapperInfosDB mapperUserBD;
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = container.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        fr = container.addFilter("RequestLoggingFilter", new RequestLoggingFilter());
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

In the second project, I import the "Framework" application context successfully, but yet haven't managed to import the WebApplicationContext as it leads to a NullPointerException.

**New project**

```
-- main
    -- java
        -- config
            - ApplicationContextConfiguration.class (extends ContextLoaderListener implements WebMvcConfigurer)
            - WebConfiguration.class (implements WebApplicationInitializer)
```

**ApplicationContextConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration extends ContextLoaderListener implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected ApplicationContext loadParentContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        // Do some stuff on applicationContext inherited from Framework
        return ac;
    }
}
```

**WebConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebApplicationInitializer {
        private static final String[] BASE_PACKAGE = { "main.java", "new.project.packages" };
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.scan(BASE_PACKAGE);
        dispatcherContext.register(AppConfig.class);
        dispatcherContext.register(AppInit.class);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr =  container.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

The StackTrace shows :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.java.config.AppInit.onStartup(AppInit.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to import Config classes in your current config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="main.java")
@Import({WebConfiguration.class, ApplicationContextConfiguration.class })
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
//Your current configuration
}
```